# laravel destroi session after change language

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem on a Laravel 10.x project
I'll start by saying that I have always used the same procedure and have never had any problems of this type

I have a multilingual site, customers arrive on the home page, make a transfer reservation by entering
departure, Arrival
and departure time
when they press the "booking" button they are redirected to a summary page where they are saved via controller all data in session

this is my route

```
Route::any('/riepilogo',[HomeController::class,'riepilogo'])->name('riepilogo')->middleware('lang');
```

and this is my controller

```
public function riepilogo(Request $request){
    
        //dd($request->all());
        $partenza=$request->indirizzo_partenza;
        $arrivo=$request->indirizzo_arrivo;
        $pax=$request->pax;
        $trolley=$request->trolley;
        $valigie=$request->valigie;
        $bici=$request->bici;
        $data_partenza=$request->data_partenza;
        $data_arrivo=$request->data_arrivo;
        $ora_arrivo=$request->ora_arrivo;
        $ora_partenza=$request->ora_partenza;
        Session()->put('indirizzo_partenza',$partenza);
        Session()->put('indirizzo_arrivo',$arrivo);
        Session()->put('pax',$pax);
        Session()->put('trolley',$trolley);
        Session()->put('valigie',$valigie);
        Session()->put('bici',$bici);
        Session()->put('data_partenza',$data_partenza);
        Session()->put('data_arrivo',$data_arrivo);
        Session()->put('ora_arrivo',$ora_arrivo);
        Session()->put('ora_partenza',$ora_partenza);
        $stati=State::all();
        //dd(Session()->all());
        Session()->save();
        return view('riepilogo',compact('stati'));
    }
```

the data is saved correctly and the session data relating to the booking is displayed in the summary form.

the problem occurs as soon as I try to change the language from this page

```
<form action="{{ route('locale', 'it') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <button class="nav-link" style="background:transparent;border:none;">
    <img src="/image/italal.png" class="flag-icon flag-icon w-50">
  </button>
</form>
<form action="{{ route('locale', 'en') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
   <button class="nav-link" style="background:transparent;border:none;">
      <img src="/image/engl.png" class="flag-icon flag-icon w-50">
   </button>
</form>
```

this is route for change lang

```
Route::post('/traduzione/{locale}',[HomeController::class,'traduzione'])->name('locale');
```

function traduzione():

```
public function traduzione(Request $request,$locale)
    {
        $allreq=$request->all();
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        App::setLocale($locale);
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($allreq);
    }
```

and
for information this is the middleware

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Localization
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }
        dd(Session()->all());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

the problem occurs right here, because when you return to the summary page, the form is no longer filled in with the session data and the session itself dd(Session()->all()) is empty

the strange thing I noticed is that if I go back from the browser and reload the page, I have the session data and the language selected again, I don't know how to solve it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace this line:

```
$allreq = $request->all();
```

by:

```
$allreq = $request->session()->all();
```

in your function traduzione in order to save data of session instead of request inputs(which are empty because you dont submit something).

another alternative, you can try:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput()
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I had tried this solution but unfortunately without having positive results, I noticed that this problem gives me the any route